# Creating a .NET application without the entire framework?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dll, frameworks, reference

I am in the process of creating a lightweight application in vb.NET, and was wondering if it is possible to create an application that uses some of the dll's within the .NET 2.0 framework, without actually using the framework itself.

For instance, can I take the dlls from the .NET directory that the app will reference (and only those dlls that it references), put them into a folder inside the app's directory, and then just change the reference path to that new location? That way, when the app is installed on pc's without .net framework installed, the dlls can just be zipped and copied over to the newly installed app directory.

This may all sound a bit confusing, just let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Regardless of the presence of the DLLs, if the .NET Framework isn't installed on the target machine then the OS won't know how to use those DLLs.  To run a .NET application, the .NET Framework needs to be present.

Comment: That is what I figured, so either I go with Delphi or I just hope that all client machines have at least 2.0 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite unlikely that you'll be able to do that.

There is this thing called .net framework client profile for creating lightweight .net apps that do not need the whole framework but you still need to have that installed.

I would recommend using something like Delphi if you need a standalone exe that does not depend on anything.

Comment: I think that is what I am going to look into. Delphi is more than likely the option we will go with

Comment: The Client Profile really doesn't buy you very much. You still have to ensure that it is installed, and it's only 10-20% smaller if I remember correctly. If you don't want a dependency on the .NET Framework, you need to not target the .NET Framework. Using Delphi is an option, as is C++ and Win32.

Answer (score 1):

There is concept of [Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.
That is subset of .NET, smallest necessary fraction of .NET that client must have in order to be able to run .NET applications targeting client profile.

There is more [detailed overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc656912%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of the features you may use when targeting client profile.

Comment: unfortunately we want to go with 2.0 for now, as some of our clients have severely outdated machines.

Comment: .net 2 and .net 3.5 has exactly the same runtime, there should be no difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you move to .Net 4 or above, you need full framework on the client computers. Having said that, which OS are you targeting? Newer MS OS often come with .Net framework installed already.

Comment: I am not targeting any  specific OS, though most likely all clients will be on win xp sp3 and up.